# Unable to get the script to slide a button to the right using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written script to register a website with selenium. but i couldn't be able to find a code to slide the slider to the right to  complete the registration using python selenium webdriver. please find the website link for you reference.

[Website Link](https://member.lazada.vn/user/register).

[Image of a slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbXrP.png)

### How Can i slide the button to the right?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
sys.path.append("..")
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import datetime
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import itertools
import math
import random
import pyautogui
import pathlib 
import move 

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_argument("window-size=1280,800")
#option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
#option.add_argument('proxy-server=106.122.8.54:3128')
#Setting up Chrome/83.0.4103.53 as useragent
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
#option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=option)
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

browser.get("https://member.lazada.vn/user/register")

WebDriverWait(browser, 1500).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/input"))).send_keys("+910000000")
time.sleep(3)

#SLIDER RIGHT SCRIPT
        
width = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#nc_2__scale_text span').size['width']

slidebar = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.nc_iconfont.btn_slide')

move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent * width / 100, 0).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get('https://member.lazada.vn/user/register')
slider = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#nc_2_n1z")
container = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nc-container")
move = ActionChains(driver)
move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(container.size['width'], 0).release().perform()
```

This should off_set it by the container size's width.

Answer (score 0):

You can slide the slider as following:

```
width = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#nc_2__scale_text span').size['width']

slidebar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nc_iconfont.btn_slide')

move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent * width / 100, 0).release().perform()
```

Comment: i have use this code it it shows me an error slidebar = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(.nc_iconfont.btn_slide)
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press Enter to continue...:

Comment: Sure. I forgot the `'` there. See updated answer

Comment: also another error Thank you for your support and sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent * width / 100, 0).release().perform()
AttributeError: module 'move' has no attribute 'click_and_hold'

Comment: i have updated my post with your code can you please refer it because now im getting and error as --> move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent * width / 100, 0).release().perform() AttributeError: module 'move' has no attribute 'click_and_hold'